# Is a smooth function still smooth in a sub-manifold containing its image?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Assume $f$ is a smooth map between manifolds $M$ and $N$, and $S$ is a sub-manifold of $N$ with $f(M) \subset S$. Is the map $f: M \to S$ always smooth?

Does the answer depend on whether the submanifold is embedded or immersed?

Comment: Does "submanifold" mean embedded or immersed?

Comment: @EricWofsey No.

Comment: ...That was not a yes or no question.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample?

Comment: @EricWofsey I ask if it is always true. So could you give a counterexample?

Comment: As Eric says, you should define submanifold. If it's not an embedded or immersed submanifold, I don't know what a submanifold is.

Comment: @MikeMiller, sorry, is there no other manifold in the category out of embedded or immersed?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "submanifold" other than an embedded submanifold or an immersed submanifold. And the answer to your question depends on which you mean.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For immersed submanifolds, the answer is (potentially) no.  For instance, there is an immersion $i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is a figure $8$, where you start going up and right from the middle, go around the top loop counterclockwise, then go around the bottom loop clockwise.  Now consider a map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ which traces out a path in the figure $8$ starting on the bottom left and going diagonally to the top right.  The lift of $f$ through $i$ gives a map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is not even continuous (specifically, it is discontinuous at the point where $f$ passes through the center of the figure $8$).

For embedded submanifolds, however, the answer is yes.  Let $m=\dim S$, $n=\dim N$, and $i:S\to N$ be the embedding.  By the [constant rank theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Constant_rank_theorem) applied to $i$, for each $y\in S$ there is a coordinate chart $U\subseteq S$ around $y$ and a coordinate chart $V\subseteq N$ of $i(y)$ such that $i(U)\subseteq V$, and when we identify $U$ with $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $V$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$, the map $i$ (restricted to $U$) is just the inclusion $i(t_1,\dots,t_m)=(t_1,\dots,t_m,0,\dots,0)$.  Furthermore, since $i$ is an embedding, we may assume that actually $i^{-1}(V)=U$.   For any $x\in M$, applying this with $y=f(x)$, you get that in local coordinates near $x$, $f$ is just a smooth map to $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose image lies in $\mathbb{R}^m\times\{0\}^{n-m}$.  Such a map is clearly also smooth when considered as a map to $\mathbb{R}^m$, which means exactly that $f$ is smooth as a map $M\to S$.

More generally, the argument of the previous paragraph shows that even when $S$ is only immersed in $N$, $f:M\to S$ is smooth at any point of $M$ at which it is continuous.